# git checkout warning: refname '14198' is ambiguous

Tags: git

```
$ git checkout 14198
warning: refname '14198' is ambiguous.
Updating files: 100% (8963/8963), done.
Switched to branch '14198'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/14198'.
```

why it warns "warning: refname '14198' is ambiguous."??
There is no same name tag, or remote branch names.

```
$ git branch -a | grep 14198
* 14198
  IRS-14198
  IRS-14198-API
  IRS-14198-UI
  remotes/origin/14198
  remotes/origin/IRS-14198
  remotes/origin/IRS-14198-API
  remotes/origin/IRS-14198-UI
```

If I run "git tag -l | grep 14198", it returns nothing.
so, there is no same name tag.

why?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Thank you all for your replies.
appending more outputs here:

run `git rev-list --all | grep 14198` returns nothing.

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep 14198
....
....multiple line outputs.
....only one line starts with 14198
14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606 file/path/filename
....
....

$ git cat-file -t 14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606
blob
```

It's a blob(file), not a commit.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
WOW!! Thank you everyone!!

I test it!!

**If a branch name is same as a prefix-of-a-blob-id, git checkout will warn refname 'xxxxx' is ambiguous.**

```
$ git checkout 14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606
fatal: reference is not a tree: 14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606
```

$ git checkout 14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606
fatal: reference is not a tree: 14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606 is id of a blob(not a commit). so, checkout failed.
looks like a hidden incorrect-warning-message in `git checkout`.

++++++++++++++++++++++++
checked git source code

```
    if (len == r->hash_algo->hexsz && !get_oid_hex(str, oid)) {
        if (warn_ambiguous_refs && warn_on_object_refname_ambiguity) {
            refs_found = repo_dwim_ref(r, str, len, &tmp_oid, &real_ref, 0);
            if (refs_found > 0) {
                warning(warn_msg, len, str);
                if (advice_enabled(ADVICE_OBJECT_NAME_WARNING))
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", _(object_name_msg));
            }
            free(real_ref);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

```
./environment.c:33:int warn_on_object_refname_ambiguity = 1;
```

warn_on_object_refname_ambiguity is set to 1.
don't know whether there is a command line switch to turn it off.

forget about.
it's 0:36am.
I am going to sleep.

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: It might conflict with a commit  hash (though that sounds really unlikely)

Comment: Try running `git rev-list --all --abbrev-commit --abbrev=5`. That will list the commit hashes in your repo (beware the list may be very big if you have a long history). You can also `grep` that for the ref you are looking for.

Comment: @apokryfos not *that* unlikely; just one in a million (5 hexits = 2^20 possibilities). It was bound to happen eventually to *someone*.

Comment: @hobbs it's like winning a weird dev lottery

Comment: This is one reason to use very short branch names (anything under 4 characters cannot be a hash ID, according to Git anyway) *or* always name your branches with a slash or hyphen in them (e.g., `feature/xyz` or `b-14198`). Including any non-hexadecimal character suffices, so `br14198` also works, but `b14198` could still match (it's just 16 times less likely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a commit with a hash that starts with the same sequence as the branch name you provided.

Try running `git rev-list --all --abbrev-commit --abbrev=5`. That will list the commit hashes in your repo (beware the list may be very big if you have a long history).

You can also `grep` the list of refs for the hash you are looking for.

```sh
$ git rev-list --all | grep 14198
```

You can also check the commit log to know what it refers to before creating a branch or tag:

```sh
$ git log -1 14198
```

That will always show the commit that refers to a branch or tag if present, otherwise it will show a commit with a matching hash.

As per @HelloKitty's comment, blob refs can also interfere. To search for them, use:

```sh
$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep 14198
```

Comment: Thank you!
`git rev-list --all | grep 14198` returns nothing.
`git rev-list --objects --all | grep 14198` output contains multiple lines. One of the lines start with 14198. However, it is a blob. 
```
$ git cat-file -t 14198841b0cb3735a412142617c8dd77844a4606
blob
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. We usually forgot about blobs, but those also have hashes. 
I will add that to my answer, mentioning your comment.